# File.listFiles() returns files in current working directory in Java

Tags: java, file

I ran into some strange thing regarding `File.listFiles()`.

- `new File("D:/").listFiles()` returns a list with all files and directory within the D drive (e.g. `D:/some-file-straight-from-the-D-drive.txt`, `D:/documents`).
- However, `new File("D:").listFiles()` apparently returns all files and directory within the current working directory: `D:/dist`, `D:/src`, `D:/build` (these are the folders within my Netbeans project).

How comes that the latter returns all files and directories in the current working directory? And why isn't the real working directory (like `D:/projects/Netbeans/SomeJavaProject/dist`) returned, but instead the file or directory name prefixed with `D:` (like `D:/dist`)?

Comment: That is the meaning of `D:`, as you can verify wih the command shell. It means the currently directory on the D: drive. It has nothing to do with Java whatsoever.

Comment: @DavidM Look again at what I actually said. It means the current directory *on that drive.* If you don't have such a drive, you don't have a current directory on it either. Try it with `dir C:` from various working directories and see for yourself. It's been that way for over 35 years.

Comment: Well I don't have a C: drive either. Being on Linux I've got `/` so I've never had the issue

Comment: So it's a Windows issue. Right... I really couldn't find this question on Stackoverflow, but apparently there was already an answer. Should I delete the question?